# Text boxes with icons in word documents

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm wondering if in word is it possible to create text boxes with icons, and possibly save them as a reusable style.
I would like to obtain an effect which is easily done with CSS like this page ([http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/03/09/appfabric-wcf-service-c.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20140410151239/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/03/09/appfabric-wcf-service-c.aspx)) for both code boxes and alerts (with an icon). The same effect I need is found on MSDN ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412182%28v=vs.90%29.aspx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.5/bb412182%28v=vs.90%29), yellow box with notes).

Thank you

Comment: You may want to specify in your title and question that this is a MS-word question, I almost flagged it as off topic before I saw your tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to do this with a style. A style will format text, but it won't create it.

It is possible to create a style that will set the font, margins, shading, borders, etc. using a style. The icon and title text can't be added as part of a style. You will have to add those as text and format them manually, or with a different style than the text of the note.

You could create a text box with the look you want, then copy and paste it where you need it. If you choose to do this, format the text box, select Layout, and choose In Line With Text so that the text doesn't wrap around the box if the box is narrower than the margins. This would work well for the notes style from MSDN you referenced.

Comment: Styles could help me to do it "the right way", always similar and easily updatable.
I'm a bit surprised that Word doesn't support such functionality.
Thank you for your answer